# how to squeeze a partial background image from an image sprite

Tags: css, resize, background-image, css-sprites

I have this fiddle which generates single country flags from a image sprite. I want to squeeze each flag because the width of flag seems to be too wide.

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JA97b/4/)**

For instance the Norwegian flag is too wide in the jsfiddle sample.

How can I do this? Thank you.

```css
#flag1 {
    width: 120px;
    height: 60px;
    background-image: url(http://i.hizliresim.com/e7Y5dm.png);
    background-position: -120px 0;
}

#flag2 {
    width: 120px;
    height: 60px;
    background-image: url(http://i.hizliresim.com/e7Y5dm.png);
    background-position: -480px 13800px;
}

#flag3 {
    width: 120px;
    height: 60px;
    background-image: url(http://i.hizliresim.com/e7Y5dm.png);
    background-position: -1200px 19020px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to [scale (*`transform:scale(x);`*)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform) the whole element (*the  `div` in this case*)
For example `transform:scale(0.5);` will scale the element to half its size, but keep in mind that it retains the initial space in the DOM flow.

---

Another way is to use the [`background-size` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size) to resize your image, but you will have to recalculate the positioning as well..

---

demo at http://jsfiddle.net/JA97b/5/

---

Additionally, in your CSS you should group common properties to a single class and apply that instead of repeating tem for each flag..

```
.flag{
    width: 120px;
    height: 60px;
    background-image: url(http://i.hizliresim.com/e7Y5dm.png);
}
#flag1{background-position: -120px 0;}
#flag2{background-position: -480px 13800px;}
#flag3{background-position: -1200px 19020px;}
```

and use

```
<div class="flag" id="flag1"></div>
<div class="flag" id="flag2"></div>
<div class="flag" id="flag3"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

To get exactly what you wanted I used background-size just to reduce the width of your sprite.
So I reduced the width of the sprite about one sixth and adjusted the width of the element in accordance.

```
#flag3
{
    width: 100px;
    height: 60px;
    background: url(http://i.hizliresim.com/e7Y5dm.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
    background-position: -1000px -480px;
    background-size: 1500px 780px;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mtF28/)